# ¿Can WHEN have multiple columns condition in WHEN?

Tags: sql, case

And I don't mean having consecutive AND expressions.
I mean having something like this

```
SELECT *
CASE
    WHEN column1 = 'One' THEN 1
    WHEN column2 = 'Tree' THEN Green
END AS NumbersAndColors
FROM WorldTable;
```

I have seen examples from Internet and they not seem to use this syntax but I was wondering this (I'm learning SQL). Also keep in mind I know how to use AND:

```
SELECT *
CASE
    WHEN column1 = 'One' AND column2 = 'Tree' THEN '1 and Green'
/*Ignore the fact I used 1 (in THEN clause) as a STRING instead of INT in this example*/
END AS NumbersAndColors
FROM WorldTable;
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  That seems simpler than asking.

Comment: @Andrew In a way, yes, but that only proves that this specific DBMS supports, portability/standard compliance is not revealed…

Comment: Actually there's even an `ELSE`... General documentation for on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Comment: Offtopic: Funny how minor details can reveal major facts (leading `¿` -> hispanophone)…

Comment: @Aconcagua why he can be a Spanish speaker, where this is common

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple `WHEN` conditions. Just make sure the datatype in every `THEN` expression is equal. So in your first piece of code, you should return '1' instead of 1, and 'Green' instead of Green, or your database is going to moan about it.